# LazyLoading issue when to add child to parent - hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, hibernate-mapping

I have two classes: Bundle and Commodity which are defined as bidirectional relationship. Assume that I have only have 1 entity of Bundle, and 0 of Commodity. How can I can create a commodity and establish relationship between the commodity and the bundle?

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="id", fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
List<Commodity> commodityList;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="BUNDLE_ID")
private Bundle bundle;
```

In my service class I have try this:

```
// Add commodity instance to exiting bundle.
public void addCommodityToBundle(Bundle bundle, Commodity commodity) {
    LOGGER.info("Create and Persist Commodity Instance to Bundle Entity");
    Bundle attachBundle = bundleDao.merge(bundle);

    attachBundle.getCommodityList().add(commodity);
    commodity.setBundle(attachBundle);
    bundleDao.update(attachBundle);
}
```

With above approach, I got no problem with the 1st run. But with other runs, I got DataIntegrityException cause by:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: insert or update on table "commodity" violates foreign key constraint "fk_imi7xke3iqtx6d3g7ceqfs7ud"
  Detail: Key (id)=(2) is not present in table "bundle".
```

If I run the test one more time, I will get

```
 Detail: Key (id)=(3) is not present in table "bundle".
```

I dont know why it keep trying to establish relation with nonexisting entity. I have put a lot of loggers try to debug and ensured that the bundle is existing in the table. Any idea how I should do to correct the implementation?

Comment: Show the bundleDao.merge code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@OneToMany` `mappedBy` mapping is wrong.

Instead of:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="id", fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
List<Commodity> commodityList;
```

You should have:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="bundle", fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
List<Commodity> commodityList;
```